# Adding an error message to return. SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Well, I'm trying to construct some error reporting.

Current snippet of code, which will put into a stored procedure after I get this code correct...

```
begin

    select * 
    from dbo.DIM_S17_Detail
    Where ((LEN(New_Acc_Flag) >1 or ISNUMERIC (Substring(New_Acc_flag, 1, 1)) = 1))
end
```

So, the defined datatype is either a Y/N - Alphanumeric, so it picks out `ISNUMERIC` as 1, so it will bring up the selected records which ARE numeric - so these records are incorrect...

I hope you still follow...

So, if a 'New_Acc_Flag' is TRUE, it will bring up those record(s) and should return a message something like "Y/N not selected" or "Y/N Value only".

Thanks again.

Please bear in mind I'm a noobie to SQL.

Comment: I don't really understand the question...I assume the @TaxYear variable is irrelevant to the question? Are you trying to find records where the New_acc_flag isn't either Y, N, 1 or 0, and show them separately?

Comment: MySQL or MSQL? There's no `ISNUMERIC` in MySQL

Comment: Hi Neville, Yes, I will take that out.. Didn't mean to leave that in there. Yes I am trying to find records where new_acc_flag isn't either Y or N. 

So the ISNUMERIC was used to pull out records which were NUMERIC, so this query is looking for error(s) (which are numeric).

Comment: MSQL, it wouldn't find it on the submit page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly you can use [THROW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx) or [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)